# mysql: facebook like unique id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, guid

I'm currently using UUID v1 as unique id

but, I think uuid is too long

I want to generate numeric unique id like fb and G+, which is shorter

and don't have to check if the id exist in DB or not before insert

example:

> https://plus.google.com/104560124403688998123/posts
>
> facebook/100001458264256

I'm thinking of generate it base on some user detail?

any good idea?

Comment: why not just an unsigned bigint that starts at some "high" number and increments by more than just +1?

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to simply have this be the (auto increment/numeric) identity column on the main user record.  To have it of a similar length you'll need to start your auto increment value at 100000000 or something of the sort.  You'll also need to make sure the column is wide enough to hold numbers of that size and up for more users than you think you'll have.